# Getting Request timed out in command prompt for ping smtp.gmail.com and for java program while sending email

Tags: java, email

Need to send mail through java program, Once i ran my program successfully in another machine, program is correct as far as i know, but this time it is showing time out connection, when i checked in my command prompt, also it is showing request timed out

for command prompt:

C:>ping smtp.gmail.com

Pinging gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com [74.125.69.108] with 32 bytes of data:

```
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Ping statistics for 74.125.69.109:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

---

for java program :

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
```

Comment: Maybe that is a firewall issue.

Comment: @Jens could u please guide me to check whether it is firewall issue exactly ...

Answer (score 0):

The first step in troubleshooting is to ensure you can ping locally. 
To do this:

```
Go to Start > Run, type cmd and press Enter.
Type ping 127.0.0.1 and press Enter.
If this fails, troubleshoot your firewall.
```

If that step was successful:

```
Type ping 25.x.x.x where 25.x.x.x is your own hamachi IP.
If this fails, again revisit your firewall settings.
```

If this was successful:

```
Type ping 25.x.x.x where 25.x.x.x is the IP of the target computer.
If this fails, you'll need to troubleshoot the firewall on that machine.


If you use IPv6 protocol mode, you need to type ping -6 <IPv6 address>. For example, ping -6 2620:9b::586:5b0c
```

Also try deleting default gateway if above steps wont works.